# Discord JS v13 FFmpeg not found on rootserver

Tags: javascript, node.js, ffmpeg, discord, discord.js

I just installed my DiscordJS Bot on my new rootserver, I copied the files 1:1 to the server and started the Bot. The Bot starts normal but when I try to execute a command where the bot joins a vc and plays audio it says:

```
throw new Error('FFmpeg/avconv not found!');
      ^
```

Error: FFmpeg/avconv not found!

Which is weird because I have ffmpeg and ffmpeg-static installed, and the same script works normally on my PC when I run it. Any ideas why?

Edit:
The only difference between the versions on the PC and the rootserver are the Node.js versions; PC: 16.6.0, rootserver: 17.4.0 (the rootserver is running on ubunu 11, and my PC on windows 10)

Answer (score 1):

You didn't install FFmpeg on your host yet

FFmpeg can be installed with npm:

```
npm install ffmpeg-static
```

Update: You can also install it directly using apt:

```sh
sudo apt install ffmpeg
```